# How To Add Zig Zag Border to a Box contains background image

Tags: css

I already find following perfect CSS snippet which creates  zip zag border at this [link](http://blog.eliacontini.info/post/42743847160/notes-on-css3-box-with-zig-zag-border).

```
.h-zigzag {
    background:
        linear-gradient(-135deg, #333538 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px,
        linear-gradient(135deg, #333538 5px, #fff 0) 0 5px;
    background-color: #333538;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

As you can see the code create a perfecr zig zag border but I need to add this border to a box which contains an image as:

```
 .h-zigzag {
   background: url(../img/grrenfooter.png) repeat-x top left scroll transparent;
 }
```

can you please help me to mix them? I already tried several ways but the image disappears when I mix them!

Comment: Please create a fiddle if you want to ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that, but you need masking, and as far as I know it is only available in webkit.

```css
#zigzag {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 30px, white 30px), linear-gradient(-135deg, white 15px, transparent 15px), linear-gradient(135deg, white 15px, transparent 15px);
    -webkit-mask-position: left bottom;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%, 30px 30px, 30px 30px;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/750");
    background-size: cover;
}

body {
    background-image:  repeating-linear-gradient(20deg, lightgreen, lavender 40px);   
}
```

```html
<div id="zigzag"></div>
```

This works by creating an image that has the zigzag pattern ; and also that has the upper part of the image also transparent. When we use that as a mask, it uses the background where it is transparent.

I have set the body with a stripes pattern so that it can be seen that the zig zag border is really transparent

### [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pxcXx/33/)

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You can't mix them, because both of them use the `background` property, so the last CSS code will be applied because it overrides the previous one(s).

### Solution [[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WHFAB/)]

You have to use [CSS2 multiple background feature](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multiple_backgrounds.html) and set the `background-size` individually:

```
.h-zigzag {
   height:200px;/*Set this to match with your background image*/
   width:200px;/*Set this to match with your background image*/
   background:
      linear-gradient(-135deg, #333538 5px, transparent 0) 0 5px,
      linear-gradient(135deg, #333538 5px, #fff 0) 0 5px,
      url('http://placekitten.com/200/200');/*Your image URL here*/       
   background-color: #333538;
   background-position: left bottom, left bottom, top;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   background-size:
      10px 10px,
      10px 10px,
      100% 100%;/*Your image size here*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks totymedli, but how I can get rid of the Grey background on Zip Zap part? Can we make it transparent to only display the border I mean not fill part?

Comment: @MonaCoder No, you cant make it that way. If you look at the CSS, you can see that this zig-zag is made by two diagonal `linear-gradient`. They doesn't even have a border, they are just gradients. This trick was made for decorating the bottom of the `<div>`s. You can't crop images with it. The only modification you can do is to change to zig-zag's color by replacing the two `#333538` colors with something else.