# How to make "saw tooth" edge on a website using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the "saw tooth" edge design that can be seen on this site:

https://tootal.nl/en/

Chrome's inspector told me they did in in three steps, but I was unfortunately unable to find out any more about the way it is implemented.

Any help would be appreciated (also about whether I asked the question right - It's my first time here on SO), thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe this can help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568458/how-to-create-alligator-or-sawtooth-border-using-css-or-svg
 or this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774952/making-jagged-triangle-border-in-css

Comment: It's a triangle image then put on repeat.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/nCFqb

Comment: Thank you very much, it did help!