# Linear gradient zig zag background image

Tags: css, background-color, linear-gradients

Is there any way to make this using a [background-image](/questions/tagged/background-image) instead of a solid color so that it will match the container below it?

---

*I'm aware that I could easily accomplish this with a `.svg` or `.png` image.  I would like to accomplish it purely using CSS only.*

---

```
.zigzag {
    tag:position:absolute;
    top:320px;
    z-index:99;
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    background:
        linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 30px, white 30px),
        linear-gradient(-135deg, white 19px, transparent 19px),
        linear-gradient(135deg, white 19px, transparent 19px);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100% 100%, 30px 30px, 30px 30px;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Note on the demo: it's not browser prefixed so it'd be best viewed in FF

Comment: thanks, haven't gotten to doing that yet.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further on what the desired end-result is?

Comment: I'd like the white of the zigzag to use the same image that is being used below it.  In the example I'm just using a placeholder: http://www.placehold.it/900x2000/666666 .  Imagine if that were a texture rather than a flat color.  The zigzag would need to be a texture as well or it just doesn't work as an effect.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to make a little more sense: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamcc/MaSqn/1/

Comment: So neither will be a solid color?

Comment: In the updated fiddle, the zig zag should match the cloth pattern so it looks as though the cloth has a jagged edge.

Comment: @dcc That didn't answer my question. If one is solid then the approach by GCyrillus is the way to go. If not, you'd have to do some manipulation by duplicating the image in the divider element and doing some other manipulation. Even then I don't know for sure it'd be possible

Comment: One posibility would be this one   http://stackoverflow.com/a/19082876/1926369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually forgot about this question but I resolved it quite a while back and created a demo of it on Codepen here:  http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/noAiw

css

```
body { 
  background-color:transparent;
}
div { 
  margin:0 auto;
  width:940px;
  height:300px;
}
div.top { 
  background-image:url(http://www.placehold.it/940x300/2D8ABE);
}
div.bottom { 
  background-image:url(http://www.placehold.it/940x300/A93459); 
}
#zz {
  max-width:940px;
  margin-top:-125px;
  height:15px;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 15px,#fff 15px),-webkit-linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px),-webkit-linear-gradient(135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px);background:-moz-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 15px,#fff 15px),-moz-linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px),-moz-linear-gradient(135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px);background:-o-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 15px,#fff 15px),-o-linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px),-o-linear-gradient(135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px);background:-ms-linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 15px,#fff 15px),-ms-linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px),-ms-linear-gradient(135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px);background:linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 15px,#fff 15px),linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px),linear-gradient(135deg,#fff 10px,transparent 10px);background-color:transparent;background-position:center center;background-repeat:repeat-x;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%,15px 15px,15px 15px;-moz-background-size:100% 100%,15px 15px,15px 15px;background-size:100% 100%,15px 15px,15px 15px;-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);-moz-transform:rotate(180deg);-o-transform:rotate(180deg);-ms-transform:rotate(180deg);transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

html

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div id="zz" role="separator"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with linear gradient and a plain color , you can do half of your jagged edge. one side a plain color, the other side your background texture.
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/kdjce

```
div:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    transparent ,
    transparent  50%,
    gray 50%,  
    gray
  ) 
    bottom,
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      transparent ,
      transparent  50%,
      gray 50%,  
      gray
    ) 
    bottom
    ;
  background-size:30px 30px;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  box-shadow:0 -100px/* or bigger */ 0 100px gray;/* this to fill background of parent div */
}
body {
  margin:0;
  background:url(http://www.bene.be/images/uploads/2011-blog/20111007/textures/texture-07.jpg)
    }
```

`<div><p> lets have some content</div>`
that's all i can think about with plain css. Notice the shorter CSS use for the gradient :) .

other option will be to use border-image, from a png. I have unfortunately no image (nor time to make) ready to use to produce exemple.

Comment: Thanks. But now my question is, can the gray be replaced with an image.  Ultimately I want both the top and bottom to have background-images without having to create a third image element for the zig zag border.

Comment: 2 and now 3 , what are these image ? repeating texture, landscape, else  ?