# Changing direction of css 'zigzag' border

Tags: css

I am trying to create a zigzag type border using linear gradients in css. I have the 'top' border working, but I can't seem to get the bottom one to work. The bottom one is going between a solid coloured section and a section with a background image. I can get the bottom one to work if it was a solid coloured section but the image background seems to be what is stumping me.

HTML:

```
<div class="zigzag-top"></div>
<section class="one"></section>
<div class="zigzag-bottom"></div>
<section class="two"></section>
```

CSS:

```
.zigzag-top {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #DDD 10px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(-45deg, #DDD 10px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left-top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 30px 20px;
    content:" ";
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

[And here's a JSFiddle of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/9u2Lp96k/)

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19082876/4813913

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to change the angles of the gradients by 180 degrees, set the background position to top, and position the pseudo element on the border

```
.zigzag-bottom:after {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, red 16px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(225deg, blue 16px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left top;
    top: 100%;
}
```

I have set the gradients to blue and red so that you can see what is what. Change this colors to the background color and you are done

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a10moz1/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close with zigzag-top. For zigzag-bottom, if you simply switch from #DDD to white,

```
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 10px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(-45deg, white 10px, transparent 0);
```

and absolutely position the zigzag-bottom on top of your image, you should be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you're drawing white triangles when it's on the bottom. More info here: https://localmotors.com/blog/post/zig-zag-borders-in-css/1205/

```
.zigzag-bottom {
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 8px 32px 8px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.zigzag-bottom:after {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left-bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/droo46/6a10moz1/

Comment: The issue with this is that it needs to overlap the image. I am looking to see if there's a way to essentially draw the triangles upside down.